# Is ‘cosare’ equivalent to the generic use of ‘do’ in English?

Tags: verbs, english-comparison, translation

I'm a little bit ahead of my Italian lessons, but I hear people using forms of *cosare*, but don't fully understand it. I'm trying to figure out what it means in English (or even Spanish, although English is my native tongue). The closet thing I could think of was do (when used generically, not as an auxiliary)

I understand that it's used in *Che cosa?* to mean *What?*, but I don't understand why it's necessary. I'd always thought that it meant *What happened?*, but my grandfather (born in Abruzzo, but a terrible teacher!) says it just means *What?*

I'm not entirely sure whether *cosa* is used as a noun or a verb in that question, but it seems like it would be a verb.

It reminds me of the *do* in the English *Let's do lunch*, but my grandfather said that idiom really doesn't translate into Italian very well. He suggested *Facciamo il pranzo*, but said that it would be *Cosiamo il pranzo* if I **insisted** on using *cosare*. Even though he didn't like that, he said I can use it generically for any verb, and he did give me some examples, but I don't understand it semantically.

I've tried figuring this out using Google Translate by translating sentences from both English and Spanish, but Google doesn't recognize the word *cosare*.

For example, I started with *Possiamo mangiare il pranzo di domani?* I then substitued *cosare* for *mangiare* and got *Can we cosare tomorrow?*

I thought that maybe it just doesn't translate well into English, so I tried translating it into Spanish first (in my head, not with the translator). I replaced first *comer* with *cosare* and then *almorzar* as an alternate and got *¿Podemos cosare mañana?* in Spanish for both. I tried using a 3rd phrasing in Spanish with the original question and got *avere* for the verb, but I ended up with another meaningless translation, which you could probably guess.

After getting frustrated, I decided maybe I should try something more basic and tried entering *Coso quello* for *Voglio quello*, but it still just gives me the translation of *Coso that* in English, and *CosA ese* in Spanish. That would mean *thing that* in English, but it's nonsense in Spanish too.

I tried *Io coso buono* for *Io sono buono* and *Coso bene* for *Sta bene*, and got *good thing I* for **both**, at which point I decided that was about as basic as I could possibly get and gave up.

Are there any English phrases, idioms, words, or expressions that can approximate the meaning of *cosare* in Italian? Am I at least attempting to use this verb properly?

Comment: John, can *thingamajig* and *whatsit* be used as verbs? If so, I think *cosare*, as a colloquial verb, is close enough to 'to thingamajig' and 'to whatsit'.

Comment: If you ever saw "The Smurfs", "cosare" is essentially "puffare" ("to smurf"), so you understand that it's something you don't want to use in normal conversation, besides as a placeholder for a verb you don't remember. Related: in high school we were told that Umberto Eco suggested to use "smurf" & co. (as a verb, noun, adjective, ...) as placeholder in a latin/greek translation to glue together the sentence structure before looking up the meanings of the words. A friend of mine took this too literally and in his next translation almost everything was "smurf"; the teacher was not amused. =)

Comment: (in dialects placeholders [are usually more graphic](http://www.giallochiaro.net/bazar104.htm), though)

Comment: Is this like saying *I don't know, how do you say?*. If not, I were to say *sciavi tu ieri?* could you respond with *Si, cosai*. I'm thinking of the English *Did you ski yesterday? Yes, I did* Or maybe *Hai fatto tu ieri?* *Cosai qualcosa ieri, ma non mi ricordo che cosa?* I asked this question because [this source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cosare) defines it as *to do in English*. That's the only source I could find that defined the word. Is this like the French/English *Je ne sais quoi* in English. *Oh, I did je ne sais quoi? yesterday.*

Comment: @MatteoItalia I don't remember *puffare*, but I do remember *smurf* as a verb. And we use *Google* and other nouns as verbs in English. Is it like that? I don't remember the exact word that my grandfather used, but he used another verb that he said meant nothing in and of itself, but suggested I not use it around people whom I don't know. I'll have to ask him. He's from Chieti, so it would be Southern, whatever it was.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Unfortunately, no they cannot, but thank you for the analogy. I understand your point.

Comment: @JohnQPublic: it's not a verbization like "to Google" in English (which, BTW, exists in Italian as the (ugly) "Googlare"), it's really just a placeholder for a verb we don't immediately remember at the moment. It's not used for anything else, especially not as a translation for a "real" *do* (which in general becomes "fare"); also, I'd say it's not used much in general, since the verb must be immediately clear from the context, otherwise the whole sentence becomes unintelligible.

Comment: *Googlare*? Dio mio! I know that it's a different part of speech, but is this like when we use *Um* in English to give us time to think of the word? I think Wikitionary means *to do* as a generic placeholder verb, as in *I do that for a living*, instead of *I work in advertising*. I understand now what my grandfather meant when he said *it's like the word **it**, only it's a verb*. It's the same rule with *it*, the context must be clear for it to be understandable.

Comment: @JohnQPublic cosare : it's simply awful ...do not use it even if you are alone, door locked, talking at your mirror.

Comment: It's like _thingy_ but it's a verb.

Comment: Questo mi sembra più un commento che una vera risposta, @MauroVanetti.

Comment: @Charo Sì, grazie.

Comment: Tuttavia, @MauroVanetti, da molto tempo non ti vedevamo su questo sito. Sono contenta del tuo ritorno e aspettiamo nuovi tuoi contributi. :)

Comment: Grazie @Charo, sono molto distratto ma vi seguo sempre e siete proprio una bella squadra!

Comment: I am Italian and I never heard "cosare" in my life.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, *cosa* in *Che cosa?* is indeed a noun, used to reinforce the question. Since *cosa* means generally any object or action (analogue to "something" or "anything" in English), you can omit it without losing the meaning:

> Che? Cosa? Che cosa?
>   What?
>   Che (cosa) sta succedendo?
>   What's (that, that is) happening?

The verb *cosare* is used only if you don't remember the proper word to describe an action. In English, it'd be like saying **"do that thing," assuming that your listener knows or can guess what you are talking about.** You can't translate it directly with "to do" or "to have."

> Ieri ho cosato una cosa.
>   Yesterday I, you know, did that, you know, a thingy.

It's better not to use *cosare* in any other context and certainly not to try to use it as generic "to do," unless you intend it to be ironic. Taking your example, *cosiamo il pranzo*: it's unclear whether you'd mean *facciamo il pranzo* "let's have lunch," *saltiamo il pranzo* "let's skip lunch" or, maybe, *buttiamo il pranzo* "let's throw the meal away."
Italian comedian Paolo Cevoli, for instance, [has made popular the sentence](https://youtu.be/B38jnTnErpk?t=4m1s):

> Con questo cosa voglio dire? Non lo so, però c'ho ragione e i fatti mi cosano!
>   What do I mean by that? I have no idea, but I'm right and the facts do me you-know-what!

In this case, the intended expression would be *i fatti mi danno ragione* "the facts support me" (hence I'm right). But since it's not clear from the verb *cosare* what exactly those facts do, it might as well be *i fatti mi contraddicono* "the facts disprove my opinion" (because I'm an arrogant idiot who doesn't know what he's talking about). The uncertain meaning of *cosare*, thus, results in a joke.

Comment: Added warning: use "cosare" in (very) informal speech only!

Comment: @martina http://www.paoloalbani.it/Coso.html :)

Comment: To be honest, any Italian I use at this point is informal. I'm still mixing up all my Italian and Spanish prepositions, articles, and conjunctions. I had to stop focusing on writing because the *ch/qu* thing was killing me LOL. Anyway, I translate (I'm certainly no authority) *I fatti mi danno ragione* as *I'm right*. So doesn't *I fatti mi cosano ragione* mean the same **in the same conversation**? I'd wanted the tranlator to give me the English version of this: *ho cosato una cosa,* which it still won't, but I think i get it now. Grazie.

Comment: @JohnQ *i fatti mi danno ragione* means *the facts **show/confirm** my opinion is right*. *i fatti mi cosano ragione* would mean *the facts **do something** with my opinion*. So, no, it doesn't mean the same, even in the same conversation. It might mean that the facts are in your favor, but it might mean just the opposite, too. The key point of *cosare* as a verb is that it may mean anything at all.

Comment: @JohnQ It seems that your question comes from the English usage of "do/have," avoiding repetition of the previously used verb (*Did you read that book? - I did. / Have you prepared a guest list? - I have.*) Please note that in this case in Italian, you must repeat the verb, or, if anything, use *fare* (*Hai letto quel libro? - L'ho letto. / Hai preparato la lista degli ospiti? - Sì, l'ho già fatta.*). In any case, it has nothing to do with *cosare.*

Comment: @I.M. I'd only come to that conclusion after finding the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cosare) entry that defined it as *to do*. Prior to that, I did not think so. It was the only source I could find that defined the word. As far as repeating the verb goes, it's the same rule in Spanish, although *Sí* would work for *yes I did*. I'd always thought Italian followed the same rule, but recently wondered if *cosare* provided an alternative. I understand now that it does not.

Comment: @John Yeah, I see. Actually, I appreciate your asking. I'd say that the Wiktionary is not perfectly correct in this case and it just should've been more clear if used comma instead of semicolon, so that the translation was not "to do;" but "to do something, used in place of a verb one does not know."

Comment: @I.M. I've never heard anyone using such a verb, even informally. It sounds awful to me: nothing to do with "cosa" and "coso", which instead are often used and occupy a well deserved place in Italian language. Do you know where in Italy, one can hear that verb ?

Comment: Sorry guys, as stated before 'cosare' is not used in italian (and i mean never by no one, not rarely). Anyway it seems like it exists in vocabulary.

Comment: That it is not used is false: I heard it used many times, _and_ I used it myself sometimes. It is not that common, but not absent either. I'm from Lombardy, Brianza. Anyway, [this](http://www.etimo.it/?term=cosare) is a good definition in my opinion. And I guess _puffare_ is a very good analogy. And @JohnQPublic I edited the Wiktionary entry to have it define _cosare_ as _to do something with_, which codes the idea that this verb substitutes any transitive verb which won't come into one's mind but (should) be clear from context - as the link says.

Comment: Is there any implication that *cosare* is back-formed from noun *cosa*? (and consequently being very informal)

Answer (score 8):

The verb "Cosare" doesn't really exist in Italian. Or, at least, it isn't used. To translate the English verb "to do" in Italian, we use the verb "fare"; the verb "fare" is used to indicate generic actions. For example,
*Facciamo matematica* is a generic form for *Studiamo matematica*.
In this sense, the verb "cosare" is simply unused.
For this reason, Google doesn't give a translation for "cosare".
Used as "che cosa?" or "cosa?", it is equivalent to "what?", and its sense is neither of verb nor of noun, because in this context it is an adverb.

Comment: I do understand that *fare* is closer to *to do* as an action (this one is pretty easy because it's also used as *fare* in English: e.g. *I fared well on my exam*, *I'm faring relatively well with my Italian lessons*, *Fare thee well*, etc.). I'm having a hard time of grasping the concept of *a generic verb*. I made the connection through Wiktionary though; I'd never heard that prior to reading their entry for *cosare*. I'm thinking of it as something like [*to do* in #9](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/do). As for *Che cosa?*, I just don't understand why *Che?* isn't sufficient.

Comment: @JohnQPublic… I guess it actually is :). _Che?_, _Che cosa?_ and _Cosa?_ are all equivalent, though _Che?_ is less common than the others at least in spoken language. Literally it would be _What thing?_. I do not know how this developed, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @Andrea in my opinion the _cosa_ in _che cosa?_ is a noun, as I said in the comment. When _cosa?_ is alone, I guess it is a shortening of _che cosa?_, rather than an adverbial use of _cosa_.

Comment: @JohnQPublic I agree with you (as you can se from my vote). I will only add that "Che?" is certainly used in Tuscany, where I come from. And I trink also in some of our southern regions. I don't think I have ever heard it in Genoa or in Milan.

Answer (score 7):

Well, here is my 2 cents:

*Cosare* is very informal and slightly humorous in tone.

I find if *very* hard to capture its *tone* in English, and as a native speaker of Italian I think that "doing stuff with the thing" doesn't quite cut it, although it's pretty close.

The thing is, "cosa" is a **noun** which is used as a verb, which is somewhat less common in Italian than in English - e.g. we say "cercare su Google" instead of "Google it", "Googlare" still sounds wrong to the native ear - it is pretty much a *deliberate act* of grammatical sabotage, which is why it's both *humorous* in tone and *low-registry*.

It′s hard to give a translation of "cosare" because it basically *doesn′t mean anything*, it′s essentially a placeholder.

To convey the meaning as well as the tone I think one should **rewrite the entire sentence** in, well, pretty much this style, using a bit of creativity: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BuffySpeak:

> *Any of a variety of speech patterns used to indicate that a character, while
> intelligent, is perhaps too young, too inexperienced and/or
> insufficiently educated (or simply talks too fast) to properly express
> the complex ideas and thoughts that they clearly possess.*
>
> *One of the most obvious elements is a **lack of relevant vocabulary**, leading to both
> **unconventional adjectival-noun structures like "shooty-gun thing"**, and incomplete, floundering similes that turn back on themselves in
> frustration: "That idea went over like... like... like a thing that
> doesn't go over very well." Metaphorgotten is frequently a side
> effect. Often includes Oh God, with the Verbing! or similar. And
> sometimes Name McAdjective is employed.*

Notice "lack of relevant vocabulary" (check) and "unconventional structures" (check).

Taking  a (perhaps extreme) example from that wiki:
"People Who Fight And Stuff For Money And It's Fake" (meaning professional wrestlers) would probably be aptly rendered in Italian as "i tizi muscolosi in costume che si **cosano** per finta" (~~the ripped, costumed guys who fake-*cosano* each other).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

"Cosare" should, in my opinion, used only while joking or in *really* colloquial situations, otherwhise you will sound really slappy. Never use it while writing.

Only under this conditions, you can use it in place of any verb that can be related with doing something.

Answer (score 2):

"che" and "cosa" are interchangeable and they can also be used both at the same time

> A: I broke it!
>   B: what?
>
> A: l'ho rotto!
>   B: cosa? (pronoun)
>
> A: l'ho rotto!
>   B: che? (pronoun) (less common, depends on a zone)
>
> A: l'ho rotto!
>   B: che cosa? (pronoun + noun)

"cosare" is terrible, and you should totally avoid using it, it doesn't have a real meaning and it doesn't have any rules, it's just a verb that can be used potentially as a substitute of any verb.

Comment: As far as actually using this verb goes, I'm thinking I'd only use it informally, and I think I'd probably limit it to people **my own age or younger**. This is a word that I'd use in contexts similar to those for which I'd use slang or colloquial words in English. I'd use it more to sound natural and informal.

Answer (score 2):

**Verb**

cosare

(*transitive*) **To do**; used in place of a verb one does not know or remember at the moment.

> Provo a cosare la spina e vediamo che succede! - I try doing something
>   with the plug and let's see what happens!

**Note:**

Used in informal spoken language only.

**source** "http://en.wiktionary.org/"